# Magento 2.4.4 API PUT products

Tags: magento2

question of interest.

We are using the PUT command for updating our products, but the data in custom attributes are not cleared when not sending in the body:
rest/store_view/V1/products/sku

Is that expected behavior from Magento? We expect that a POST or PATCH is updating only the selected attributes and that a PUT would clear all attributes which are not sent in the PUT request.

Comment: Thanks for answering, we are living by this definition of a put..

PUT is a method of modifying resource where the client sends data that updates the entire resource . PATCH is a method of modifying resources where the client sends partial data that is to be updated without modifying the entire data

Comment: I understand. You'll need to modify your expectations for working with Magento's web API framework. Acceptable HTTP methods are defined in vendor/magento/module-webapi/etc/webapi_base.xsd, and are limited to GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you describe would probably cause a lot of trouble, as many shops use a bunch of custom attributes. So I'd say it's expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior.

Here's the TLDR for anyone else who comes across this question. Your API endpoint is defined in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/webapi.xml`. The PUT method with this endpoint calls the ProductRepositoryInterface's `save` method:

```
<route url="/V1/products/:sku" method="PUT">
    <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="save" />
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::products" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

This interface is implemented by `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository`, and its `save` method expects a ProductInterface parameter which, critically, you have not provided, and cannot provide, in your API call:

```
public function save(ProductInterface $product, $saveOptions = false)
{
    $assignToCategories = false;
    $tierPrices = $product->getData('tier_price');
    $productDataToChange = $product->getData();
    // other things happen
}
```

So where does the `$product` parameter come from? In Magento's API system, parameters provided to API service classes are created [using reflection](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html):

> Because of this, Magento uses reflection to automatically create these
> classes and sets data that you have submitted in JSON or HTTP array
> syntax onto an instance of the expected PHP class when calling the
> service method.

I don't know the deep magic of reflection well enough to point you to the place that it happens; but I expect that by providing the SKU, you tell Magento to create the `$product` parameter from the existing product identified by that SKU.

By the time you hit the `save` method, then, your `$product` object exists with all the data you'd expect an existing product to have. The repository will treat it just like it would any other product you're saving to repo: namely, saving new data without overwriting existing data you haven't explicitly changed.